# Node Js express router not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, express

js and i am learning node js along with express and I was learning express routing I have following code in rest.js

```
    const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const widgetRouter = require('./rest/widgets');

const app1 = express(); 

const server = http.createServer(app1);



app1.get('/api',widgetRouter);


server.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('server started in port 3000');

});



const app = express();
```

and I also have widgets.js file

```
const express = require('express');

const widgetRouter = express.Router();

widgetRouter.route("/widgets")
    .get(function(req,res){
        res.json({"abc":"hello"});
    })
    .post();

widgetRouter.route("/widgets/:widgetId")
    .get()
    .put()
    .delete();



module.exports = widgetRouter;
```

but When I try to test the rest api(http://localhost:3000/api/widgets) from postman it says Cannot GET /api/widgets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have imported and initialized the *express* module, but then you start a server with the *http* module. You should use only Express:

Also you should use `app.use('/api',widgetRouter)` instead of `app.get('/api', widgetRouter)` which is an express middleware.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 

const widgetRouter = require('./rest/widgets');

app.use('/api', widgetRouter);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Home');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('server started in port 3000');
});
```

Comment: I used that one too 
I tried starting with app1.listen in rest.js
but it didn't work

Comment: @ujjwalsingh What error is it giving you? Maybe the require for the widgetRouter has the wrong path, or maybe you're still using two different instances of Express (app and app1) and you're mixing them up (there should only be one)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try that.

rest.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const  router = express.Router();

const app = express();

require('./widgets')(app, router);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Home');
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('server started in port 3000');
});
```

widgets.js

```
module.exports = function(app, router){
    router.route("/widgets")
        .get(function(req,res){
            res.json({"abc":"hello"});
        })
        .post();

    router.route("/widgets/:widgetId")
        .get()
        .put()
        .delete();

    app.use('/api', router);
});
```

Comment: It does work, but the way seems to be complex and not beginner friendly